# What makes up the table I can see in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

A question out of pure curiousity;

When i'm installing SQL Server 2016 Developer edition on my developer machine, I choose custom installation and have the option to pick "Database Engine Services". Is selecting this option what makes me able to see tables and columns in the first place? (through tools like SSMS). I guess that SSMS is just a tool to take the stored data and display it in the view we daily refer to by saying "tables".

[image]

Comment: You need sql server management studio

Comment: @Filburt Well I picked the "custom install" process, so I think I have to manually pick the most basic concepts in SQL as well. It even says in the feature description of my print screen: "... core service ..."

Comment: If you install only the database engine services (core services), you can connect to that instance using any application, including SSMS, to see databases, tables, columns, etc.  Of course, only the system databases and objects will be available initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the database engine services are what allows your computer to create and store databases and tables and all their component objects.   It also allows your computer to process queries against those objects.  It has nothing to do with being able to see them.

The information in the "Feature Description" box in your screenshot pretty much answers your question.

Comment: I feel your answer is a bit inconsistent. First you say "No". Then you say "database engine services are what allows your computer to create and store databases and *tables*". To me this sounds like a "Yes" to my question. What am I missing?

Comment: I see now that my question is *maybe* misleading. What I mean is really not to *see* in the sense of SSMS tables and rows, i'm rather talking about   the services that allows me to store data that is later on viewed in tools like SSMS.

Comment: Well, then yes, if that's what you meant by your question, then the answer is yes, and I was mislead by the way it was worded.